# How to upload attachment at the same time as the document itself

Tags: angularjs, couchdb

I would like to be able to upload attachments at the same time as saving the document itself (that is, not after the document already exists, for example).

The angular application is served from inside a design documents HTML attachment, and has dependency on `ngResource`. I have made a factory for a CouchDB document (examples in [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) for brevity):

```
factory('Resource', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/mydb/:id', {id: '@_id', rev: '@_rev'}, update: method: 'PUT'])
```

and a directive (from [here](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)):

```
directive('fileModel', ['$parse', ($parse) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    elem.bind 'change', -> scope.$apply ->
      $parse(attrs.fileModel).assign scope, elem[0].files[0] ])
```

and a form input:

```
<input type="file" file-model="attachment" accept="image/*">
```

[I've read](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments) that after `new Resource`, I could append to its `._attachments`-hash new objects in the form:

```
attachment.filename: { content_type: attachment.type, data: btoa attachment }
```

And different variations where instead of `btoa` there have been `FileReader` and `FormData` solutions.

But I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

Do you know if this is at all possible, or should I just be doing file uploads only after the document has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the tumbleweed-badge, so here goes a self-answer.

There are many ways, but here's one way I got it to work. Basically needs `FileReader` from browser, and to strip the base64 "headers":

```
directive('fileread', ->
  scope: fileread: '='
  link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    scope.fileread = {}
    elem.bind 'change', (change) ->
      [].slice.apply(change.target.files).forEach (image) ->
        hdrln  = ('data:;base64,' + image.type).length
        reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = (load) -> scope.$apply ->
          scope.fileread[image.name] =
            content_type: image.type
            data: load.target.result.slice hdrln
        reader.readAsDataURL image
)
```

Which  can be used in the form like:

```
<input type="file" fileread="images" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

after which, there will be a variable `$scope.images` available in the controller, where you can just throw it into the parent document object: `$scope.doc._attachments = $scope.images`.